# How can I completely stop all Kinect streams and functions on window close?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I've been playing around with Kinect for Windows SDK 1.8 for a bit, just re-familiarizing myself with it after some time away. I have a basic application running that uses the color and skeleton streams to overlay a skeleton on a video feed of the user, while also displaying their torso's X, Y, and Z coordinates in realtime. All of this works perfectly, but I've run into an issue with shutting the application down. A first, my Window_Close event looked like this:

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Turn off timers.
    RefreshTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    RefreshTimer.Stop();

    UpdateTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    UpdateTimer.Stop();

    // Turn off Kinect
    if (this.mainKinect != null)
    {
        try
        {
            this.mainKinect.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        this.TxtBx_KinectStatus.Text += "\n[" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString() + "] " + this.mainKinect.UniqueKinectId.ToString() + " has been turned off.";
    }

    // Shut down application
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

I added the 'Application.Current.Shutdown()' only because my program would hang and never actually close when I closed the window. I stepped through the function to find that it hangs on this.mainKinect.Stop(), where mainKinect is the Kinect object referring to the physical Kinect. I thought that maybe it couldn't shut down both streams properly, so I added

```
this.mainKinect.ColorStream.Disable();
this.mainKinect.SkeletonStream.Disable();
```

just before the Stop(). I found out that it actually hangs on the SkeletonStream.Disable(), and I don't know why. Most of the rest of my code is straight from their examples, so I don't know why this doesn't work. If you have any ideas, or would like me to post more of my code, please don't hesitate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always check all streams, if they are enabled. Any enabled stream I disable, the next step to detach all previously attached eventhandlers, at the end I call the Stop() in a try-catch block and logs the Exception Message to get a hint in the case of any problem.

```
public void StopKinect()
{
   if (this.sensor == null)
   {
       return;
   }

   if (this.sensor.SkeletonStream.IsEnabled)
   {
      this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Disable();
   }

   if (this.sensor.ColorStream.IsEnabled)
   {
      this.sensor.ColorStream.Disable();
   }

   if (this.sensor.DepthStream.IsEnabled)
   {
      this.sensor.DepthStream.Disable();
   }

   // detach event handlers
   this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= this.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;

   try
   {
      this.sensor.Stop()
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine("unknown Exception {0}", e.Message)
   }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot when I'm back in work on Monday. The only thing is, it doesn't seem to throw an exception on Stop(), it just sits there.

Comment: I remenber there was in some older version (1.5 or 1.6) of the sdk a "bug", in that way, that if you forgot once to disable the streams before stop, that you have to power off the kinect to get disconnected properly. I ran into this problem, which was gone, after I used to stop the kinect in the above way, but I did not test if the bug exists with newer sdk.

Comment: Interesting, I'll restart the Kinect and see if this issue goes away, then. I'm using SDK 1.8, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I added your method to my code and restarted the Kinect, and everything works fine now. Just a note, I had to do both of these in order for it to work. Just adding the code didn't help. So thank you very much! That's an interesting bug in the Kinect.